# Submitting a form in Laravel using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Ajax works well for pre-existing forms. But if I add a new form using it and submit it, then I get to the method page.

Added a new form, filled in the field and clicked Submit: http://joxi.ru/DmBOW4KUzep962

I get to the method page, instead of displaying the result in the console: http://joxi.ru/EA4P710TOekbOA

After reloading the page, everything works well.

What could be the matter, tell me please.

Front:

```
$('.add-answer-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `/admin/courses/48/lessons/96/answerAdd`,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              console.log('!!!!!', data);
            }
          });
      });
```

Back:

```
   public function answerAdd(Request $request, Course $course, Lesson $lesson, Test $test, Answer $answer){
        $this->answer->fill($request->all())->save();
        return response ()->json ($this);
   }
```

Comment: Well, to me it looks like you are not doing anything with your response in the success callback. You need to be injecting/building the html based on the response. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @KurtFriars, The answer should at least get to the console, as here: http://joxi.ru/ZrJl84xcME80Z2

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your problem. Are you saying that the answer is not added in the json returned from your controller, but on page reload the answer is there?

Comment: @KurtFriars, Not really. The answer comes in json format, but the URL changes to the called method, as I showed in the screenshot, instead of just returning the result of the controller to the console.

Comment: Ok so your problem is that you are being redirected when the ajax response for the added answer button succeeds? If yes, then can you capture the server response in your network inspector and share it?

Comment: @KurtFriars, yes that's right.
Console:
http://joxi.ru/ZrJl84xcMEOK92
Network
http://joxi.ru/vAWa6MEsqbndem
http://joxi.ru/ZrJl84xcMEOL92

Comment: You need to show the http response before you get redirected, in your network tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216926/discussion-between-artem-and-kurt-friars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows:
Instead of this:

```
$ ('.add-answer-form').on('submit', function (e) {
```

Added this:

```
$ ('#quest-add-form').on('submit', '.add-answer-form', function (e) {
```

This is suitable in cases where you need to work with the form that was added by Ajax.

Comment: Good job Artem!